# Webdriverio script does not type numbers in field of type tel built using Salesforce Omniscript

Tags: salesforce, webdriver-io

I am trying to fill a form using Webdriverio (Typescript) + BDD.
The script enters chars for all types of questions except for mobile number field which is of type tel. The type is set in Salesforce Omniscript.[image]